# Is there a way to override collection that has been initialized by auto-property initialize syntax with values from configuration in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard, .net-core-configuration

I have a class that holds my configuration values:

```
public class DummyConfiguration
    {
        public List<DummyConfigurationObject> DummyConfigurationCollection { get; set; } =
            new List<DummyConfigurationObject>
            {
                new DummyConfigurationObject
                {
                    DummyField = "DummyConfigurationObject1",
                },
                new DummyConfigurationObject
                {
                    DummyField = "DummyConfigurationObject2",
                },
            };
    }
```

I use auto-initialized properties to provide some reasonable default that works for me.

And here is my appsettings.yaml:

```
DummyConfigurationCollection:
    - DummyField: DummyConfigurationObject3
    - DummyField: DummyConfigurationObject4
    - DummyField: DummyConfigurationObject5
```

When I call configuration.Get().DummyConfigurationCollection.Count I'd get 5 cause collection is already initialized and default binder just uses Add method to add additional entries. But what I want instead is to completely replace my default if there are some values in my configuration file that correspond to this property.

Is this possible with default configuration binder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, what you can do is configure your application like this:

```
services.Configure<DummyConfiguration>(options => {
 DummyConfiguration.DummyConfigurationCollection.Clear();
 return Configuration.GetSection("DummyConfiguration").Bind(options)
});
```

It's a overload of Configure which allows you to configure how the binding is being done. In this case we're cleaning all entries on the resulting options instance prior to binding the actual configuration values.

Later you can use this on any other service with `IOptions<DummyConfiguration>` and it will show just the configured values, not the default ones.

Here's a repo on github with my testing: https://github.com/bison92/IConfigurationCollectionBinding/tree/c29534f41cf07ea22107493d45999fe546462406

**EDIT**

As you want to use the `Configuration.Get()` there's no way to modify its behavior, any other than specifying if you want to try to bind private properties or not AFAIK.

So you might want to try implementing your custom `ICollection` for instance back it with 2 lists (defaults, currents) and override its methods so it responds with currents or defaults but always modifies the currents.

```
public class DefaultBackedCollection<T> : ICollection<T>
{
    private readonly IList<T> defaults;
    private readonly IList<T> currents = new List<T>();
    public DefaultBackedCollection(List<T> defaultElements)
    {
        defaults = defaultElements ?? new List<T>();
    }
    public int Count => currents.Any() ? currents.Count : defaults.Count;

    public bool IsReadOnly => false;

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        currents.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        currents.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return currents.Any() ? currents.Contains(item) : defaults.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        if (currents.Any())
        {
            currents.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
        }
        else 
        {
            defaults.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex); 
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return currents.Any() ? currents.GetEnumerator() : defaults.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public bool Remove(T item) => currents.Remove(item);

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return currents.Any() ? currents.GetEnumerator() : defaults.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Take a look at the updated working example: https://github.com/bison92/IConfigurationCollectionBinding

Comment: Sorry, but this is not what I need. As you can see from the question I'm using instance of configuration to access my configuration object: configuration.Get<DummyConfiguration>().DummyConfigurationCollection. IOptions and DI is not an option for me. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Are you kidding me? You're doing aspnetcore without DI?

Comment: I'm doing .netstandard but it's not a question here :) Anyway, your solution will remove all default values even if there are no corresponding values in config file, which makes default values kinda pointless :)

Comment: Ok 4 "netcore" tags made me thought this was netcore not netstandard. In any case you don't want to not use DI, without it unit testing will be painfull if not impossible.

Comment: Nice idea with custom collection. I'll accept the answer cause it looks like it is as close as I could get to desired implementation taking into account all the constraints. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not following this, in your first code example DummyConfiguration is a Class Type, you can't get the collection inside it. Unless pre .net 5 allowed that somehow???

Comment: Sorry @Tod its been one year and a half. I think the first part of my answer is a misunderstanding of the OP question, and then on the EDIT part you have the real answer.